ebpf XDP program R2 offset is outside of the packet
I have this XDP program to parse DNS packet to get the query domain name and lookup the domain name in bpf map. https://github.com/vincentmli/xdp-tools/blob/dns-deny/xdp-dns/xdp_dns.bpf.c. I got verifier error below:
xdp-loader load -vvv -m skb lo xdp-dns/xdp_dns.bpf.o

  libbpf: prog 'xdp_dns': -- BEGIN PROG LOAD LOG --
Validating xdp_dns() func#0...
0: R1=ctx(off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
; int xdp_dns(struct xdp_md *ctx)
0: (bf) r6 = r1                       ; R1=ctx(off=0,imm=0) R6_w=ctx(off=0,imm=0)
; if (bpf_xdp_adjust_meta(ctx, -(int)sizeof(struct meta_data)))
1: (18) r2 = 0xfffffff8               ; R2_w=4294967288
3: (85) call bpf_xdp_adjust_meta#54   ; R0_w=scalar()
4: (bf) r1 = r0                       ; R0_w=scalar(id=1) R1_w=scalar(id=1)
5: (b7) r0 = 2                        ; R0_w=2
; if (bpf_xdp_adjust_meta(ctx, -(int)sizeof(struct meta_data)))
6: (55) if r1 != 0x0 goto pc+81       ; R1_w=0
; c->end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;
7: (61) r2 = *(u32 *)(r6 +4)          ; R2_w=pkt_end(off=0,imm=0) R6_w=ctx(off=0,imm=0)
; c->end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;
8: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -8) = r2         ; R2_w=pkt_end(off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0 fp-8_w=pkt_end
; c->pos = (void *)(long)ctx->data;
9: (61) r4 = *(u32 *)(r6 +0)          ; R4_w=pkt(off=0,r=0,imm=0) R6_w=ctx(off=0,imm=0)
; md = (void *)(long)ctx->data_meta;
10: (61) r3 = *(u32 *)(r6 +8)         ; R3_w=pkt_meta(off=0,r=0,imm=0) R6_w=ctx(off=0,imm=0)
; if ((void *)(md + 1) > c.pos)
11: (bf) r1 = r3                      ; R1_w=pkt_meta(off=0,r=0,imm=0) R3_w=pkt_meta(off=0,r=0,imm=0)
12: (07) r1 += 8                      ; R1=pkt_meta(off=8,r=0,imm=0)
; if ((void *)(md + 1) > c.pos)
13: (2d) if r1 > r4 goto pc+74        ; R1=pkt_meta(off=8,r=8,imm=0) R4=pkt(off=0,r=0,imm=0)
; PARSE_FUNC_DECLARATION(ethhdr)
14: (bf) r1 = r4                      ; R1_w=pkt(off=0,r=0,imm=0) R4=pkt(off=0,r=0,imm=0)
15: (07) r1 += 14                     ; R1_w=pkt(off=14,r=0,imm=0)
; PARSE_FUNC_DECLARATION(ethhdr)
16: (2d) if r1 > r2 goto pc+71        ; R1_w=pkt(off=14,r=14,imm=0) R2=pkt_end(off=0,imm=0)
17: (15) if r4 == 0x0 goto pc+70      ; R4=pkt(off=0,r=14,imm=0)
; *eth_proto = eth->h_proto;
18: (71) r0 = *(u8 *)(r4 +12)         ; R0_w=scalar(umax=255,var_off=(0x0; 0xff)) R4=pkt(off=0,r=14,imm=0)
19: (71) r5 = *(u8 *)(r4 +13)         ; R4=pkt(off=0,r=14,imm=0) R5_w=scalar(umax=255,var_off=(0x0; 0xff))
20: (67) r5 <<= 8                     ; R5_w=scalar(umax=65280,var_off=(0x0; 0xff00))
21: (4f) r5 |= r0                     ; R0_w=scalar(umax=255,var_off=(0x0; 0xff)) R5_w=scalar()
; *eth_proto = eth->h_proto;
22: (6b) *(u16 *)(r3 +0) = r5         ; R3=pkt_meta(off=0,r=8,imm=0) R5=scalar()
; ||  *eth_proto == __bpf_htons(ETH_P_8021AD)) {
23: (15) if r5 == 0xa888 goto pc+1    ; R5=scalar()
24: (55) if r5 != 0x81 goto pc+16     ; R5=129
; PARSE_FUNC_DECLARATION(vlanhdr)
25: (bf) r6 = r4                      ; R4=pkt(off=0,r=14,imm=0) R6_w=pkt(off=0,r=14,imm=0)
26: (07) r6 += 18                     ; R6_w=pkt(off=18,r=14,imm=0)
27: (b7) r0 = 2                       ; R0_w=2
; PARSE_FUNC_DECLARATION(vlanhdr)
28: (2d) if r6 > r2 goto pc+59        ; R2=pkt_end(off=0,imm=0) R6_w=pkt(off=18,r=18,imm=0)
29: (15) if r1 == 0x0 goto pc+58      ; R1=pkt(off=14,r=18,imm=0)
; *eth_proto = vlan->encap_proto;
30: (69) r5 = *(u16 *)(r4 +16)        ; R4=pkt(off=0,r=18,imm=0) R5_w=scalar(umax=65535,var_off=(0x0; 0xffff))
; *eth_proto = vlan->encap_proto;
31: (6b) *(u16 *)(r3 +0) = r5         ; R3=pkt_meta(off=0,r=8,imm=0) R5=scalar(umax=65535,var_off=(0x0; 0xffff))
; ||  *eth_proto == __bpf_htons(ETH_P_8021AD)) {
32: (15) if r5 == 0xa888 goto pc+2    ; R5=scalar(umax=65535,var_off=(0x0; 0xffff))
33: (bf) r1 = r6                      ; R1_w=pkt(off=18,r=18,imm=0) R6=pkt(off=18,r=18,imm=0)
34: (55) if r5 != 0x81 goto pc+6      ; R5=129
; PARSE_FUNC_DECLARATION(vlanhdr)
35: (bf) r1 = r4                      ; R1_w=pkt(off=0,r=18,imm=0) R4=pkt(off=0,r=18,imm=0)
36: (07) r1 += 22                     ; R1_w=pkt(off=22,r=18,imm=0)
; PARSE_FUNC_DECLARATION(vlanhdr)
37: (2d) if r1 > r2 goto pc+50        ; R1_w=pkt(off=22,r=22,imm=0) R2=pkt_end(off=0,imm=0)
38: (15) if r6 == 0x0 goto pc+49      ; R6=pkt(off=18,r=22,imm=0)
; *eth_proto = vlan->encap_proto;
39: (69) r5 = *(u16 *)(r4 +20)        ; R4=pkt(off=0,r=22,imm=0) R5_w=scalar(umax=65535,var_off=(0x0; 0xffff))
; *eth_proto = vlan->encap_proto;
40: (6b) *(u16 *)(r3 +0) = r5         ; R3=pkt_meta(off=0,r=8,imm=0) R5=scalar(umax=65535,var_off=(0x0; 0xffff))
; md->ip_pos = c.pos - (void *)eth;
41: (bf) r0 = r1                      ; R0_w=pkt(off=22,r=22,imm=0) R1=pkt(off=22,r=22,imm=0)
42: (1f) r0 -= r4                     ; R0_w=scalar() R4=pkt(off=0,r=22,imm=0)
; md->ip_pos = c.pos - (void *)eth;
43: (6b) *(u16 *)(r3 +2) = r0         ; R0_w=scalar() R3=pkt_meta(off=0,r=8,imm=0)
; if (md->eth_proto == __bpf_htons(ETH_P_IP)) {
44: (55) if r5 != 0x8 goto pc+42      ; R5=8
; PARSE_FUNC_DECLARATION(iphdr)
45: (bf) r4 = r1                      ; R1=pkt(off=22,r=22,imm=0) R4_w=pkt(off=22,r=22,imm=0)
46: (07) r4 += 20                     ; R4_w=pkt(off=42,r=22,imm=0)
47: (b7) r0 = 2                       ; R0_w=2
; PARSE_FUNC_DECLARATION(iphdr)
48: (2d) if r4 > r2 goto pc+39        ; R2=pkt_end(off=0,imm=0) R4_w=pkt(off=42,r=42,imm=0)
49: (15) if r1 == 0x0 goto pc+38      ; R1=pkt(off=22,r=42,imm=0)
; switch (ipv4->protocol) {
50: (71) r3 = *(u8 *)(r1 +9)          ; R1=pkt(off=22,r=42,imm=0) R3_w=scalar(umax=255,var_off=(0x0; 0xff))
; switch (ipv4->protocol) {
51: (55) if r3 != 0x11 goto pc+35     ; R3_w=17
; PARSE_FUNC_DECLARATION(udphdr)
52: (bf) r3 = r1                      ; R1=pkt(off=22,r=42,imm=0) R3_w=pkt(off=22,r=42,imm=0)
53: (07) r3 += 28                     ; R3_w=pkt(off=50,r=42,imm=0)
; PARSE_FUNC_DECLARATION(udphdr)
54: (2d) if r3 > r2 goto pc+33        ; R2=pkt_end(off=0,imm=0) R3_w=pkt(off=50,r=50,imm=0)
55: (15) if r4 == 0x0 goto pc+32      ; R4=pkt(off=42,r=50,imm=0)
; || !(udp->dest == __bpf_htons(DNS_PORT))
56: (69) r4 = *(u16 *)(r1 +22)        ; R1=pkt(off=22,r=50,imm=0) R4=scalar(umax=65535,var_off=(0x0; 0xffff))
; || !(dns = parse_dnshdr(&c)))
57: (55) if r4 != 0x3500 goto pc+30   ; R4=13568
; PARSE_FUNC_DECLARATION(dnshdr)
58: (bf) r4 = r1                      ; R1=pkt(off=22,r=50,imm=0) R4_w=pkt(off=22,r=50,imm=0)
59: (07) r4 += 40                     ; R4_w=pkt(off=62,r=50,imm=0)
; PARSE_FUNC_DECLARATION(dnshdr)
60: (2d) if r4 > r2 goto pc+27        ; R2=pkt_end(off=0,imm=0) R4_w=pkt(off=62,r=62,imm=0)
61: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -16) = r4       ; R4_w=pkt(off=62,r=62,imm=0) R10=fp0 fp-16_w=pkt
; if (!(udp = parse_udphdr(&c))
62: (15) if r3 == 0x0 goto pc+25      ; R3=pkt(off=50,r=62,imm=0)
63: (b7) r0 = 0                       ; R0_w=0
; if (dns->flags.as_bits_and_pieces.qr
64: (69) r2 = *(u16 *)(r1 +30)        ; R1=pkt(off=22,r=62,imm=0) R2_w=scalar(umax=65535,var_off=(0x0; 0xffff))
; if (dns->flags.as_bits_and_pieces.qr
65: (57) r2 &= 128                    ; R2=scalar(umax=128,var_off=(0x0; 0x80))
; ||  dns->qdcount != __bpf_htons(1)
66: (55) if r2 != 0x0 goto pc+21      ; R2=0
; ||  dns->qdcount != __bpf_htons(1)
67: (69) r2 = *(u16 *)(r1 +32)        ; R1=pkt(off=22,r=62,imm=0) R2_w=scalar(umax=65535,var_off=(0x0; 0xffff))
; ||  dns->ancount || dns->nscount
68: (55) if r2 != 0x100 goto pc+19    ; R2_w=256
; ||  dns->ancount || dns->nscount
69: (69) r2 = *(u16 *)(r1 +34)        ; R1=pkt(off=22,r=62,imm=0) R2_w=scalar(umax=65535,var_off=(0x0; 0xffff))
; ||  dns->ancount || dns->nscount
70: (55) if r2 != 0x0 goto pc+17      ; R2_w=0
; ||  dns->ancount || dns->nscount
71: (69) r2 = *(u16 *)(r1 +36)        ; R1=pkt(off=22,r=62,imm=0) R2_w=scalar(umax=65535,var_off=(0x0; 0xffff))
; ||  dns->arcount >  __bpf_htons(2))
72: (55) if r2 != 0x0 goto pc+15      ; R2_w=0
; ||  dns->arcount >  __bpf_htons(2))
73: (69) r1 = *(u16 *)(r1 +38)        ; R1=scalar(umax=65535,var_off=(0x0; 0xffff))
; if (dns->flags.as_bits_and_pieces.qr
74: (25) if r1 > 0x200 goto pc+13     ; R1=scalar(umax=512,var_off=(0x0; 0x3ff))
75: (bf) r1 = r10                     ; R1_w=fp0 R10=fp0
; qname = parse_dname(&c);
76: (07) r1 += -16                    ; R1_w=fp-16
77: (85) call pc+11
reg type unsupported for arg#0 function parse_dname#26
caller:
 R6=pkt(off=18,r=62,imm=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=pkt_end fp-16=pkt
callee:
 frame1: R1_w=fp-16 R2=0 R3=pkt(off=50,r=62,imm=0) R4=pkt(off=62,r=62,imm=0) R5=8 R10=fp0
; char *parse_dname(struct cursor *c)
89: (b7) r3 = 0                       ; frame1: R3_w=0
90: (79) r4 = *(u64 *)(r1 +8)         ; frame1: R1_w=fp-16 R4_w=pkt_end(off=0,imm=0)
; __u8 *dname = c->pos;
91: (79) r2 = *(u64 *)(r1 +0)         ; frame1: R1_w=fp-16 R2_w=pkt(off=62,r=62,imm=0)
92: (18) r6 = 0x100000000000000       ; frame1: R6_w=72057594037927936
94: (bf) r5 = r2                      ; frame1: R2_w=pkt(off=62,r=62,imm=0) R5_w=pkt(off=62,r=62,imm=0)
95: (05) goto pc+5
; if (c->pos + 1 > c->end)
101: (bf) r7 = r5                     ; frame1: R5=pkt(off=62,r=62,imm=0) R7_w=pkt(off=62,r=62,imm=0)
102: (07) r7 += 1                     ; frame1: R7_w=pkt(off=63,r=62,imm=0)
103: (b7) r0 = 0                      ; frame1: R0_w=0
; if (c->pos + 1 > c->end)
104: (2d) if r7 > r4 goto pc+21       ; frame1: R4=pkt_end(off=0,imm=0) R7_w=pkt(off=63,r=63,imm=0)
; if ((o & 0xC0) == 0xC0) {
105: (71) r7 = *(u8 *)(r5 +0)         ; frame1: R5=pkt(off=62,r=63,imm=0) R7_w=scalar(umax=255,var_off=(0x0; 0xff))
; if ((o & 0xC0) == 0xC0) {
106: (bf) r0 = r7                     ; frame1: R0_w=scalar(id=2,umax=255,var_off=(0x0; 0xff)) R7_w=scalar(id=2,umax=255,var_off=(0x0; 0xff))
107: (57) r0 &= 192                   ; frame1: R0_w=scalar(umax=192,var_off=(0x0; 0xc0))
; if ((o & 0xC0) == 0xC0) {
108: (55) if r0 != 0xc0 goto pc+4     ; frame1: R0_w=192
; c->pos += 2;
109: (07) r5 += 2                     ; frame1: R5_w=pkt(off=64,r=63,imm=0)
110: (7b) *(u64 *)(r1 +0) = r5        ; frame1: R1=fp-16 R5_w=pkt(off=64,r=63,imm=0)
111: (bf) r0 = r2                     ; frame1: R0_w=pkt(off=62,r=63,imm=0) R2=pkt(off=62,r=63,imm=0)
112: (05) goto pc+13
; }
126: (95) exit
returning from callee:
 frame1: R0=pkt(off=62,r=63,imm=0) R1=fp-16 R2=pkt(off=62,r=63,imm=0) R3=0 R4=pkt_end(off=0,imm=0) R5=pkt(off=64,r=63,imm=0) R6=72057594037927936 R7=scalar(id=2,umax=255,var_off=(0x0; 0xff)) R10=fp0
to caller at 78:
 R0=pkt(off=62,r=63,imm=0) R6=pkt(off=18,r=63,imm=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=pkt_end fp-16=pkt
; qname = parse_dname(&c);
78: (bf) r2 = r0                      ; R0=pkt(off=62,r=63,imm=0) R2_w=pkt(off=62,r=63,imm=0)
79: (b7) r0 = 0                       ; R0_w=0
; if (!qname) {
80: (15) if r2 == 0x0 goto pc+7       ; R2_w=pkt(off=62,r=63,imm=0)
; if (bpf_map_lookup_elem(&domain_denylist, qname))
81: (18) r1 = 0xffff93604d4c2400      ; R1_w=map_ptr(off=0,ks=254,vs=1,imm=0)
83: (85) call bpf_map_lookup_elem#1
invalid access to packet, off=62 size=254, R2(id=0,off=62,r=63)
R2 offset is outside of the packet
processed 101 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 10 peak_states 10 mark_read 8
-- END PROG LOAD LOG --
  libbpf: prog 'xdp_dns': failed to load: -13
  libbpf: failed to load object 'xdp-dns/xdp_dns.bpf.o'
 libxdp: Failed to load program xdp_dns: Permission denied
Couldn't attach XDP program on iface 'lo': Permission denied(-13)



there is similar question asked Need help in XDP program failing to load with error "R7 offset is outside of the packet", not understanding the issue completely, I added check like below:
diff --git a/xdp-dns/xdp_dns.bpf.c b/xdp-dns/xdp_dns.bpf.c
index 01ab2b6..d6d8703 100644
--- a/xdp-dns/xdp_dns.bpf.c
+++ b/xdp-dns/xdp_dns.bpf.c
@@ -198,9 +198,9 @@ int xdp_dns(struct xdp_md *ctx)
                                return XDP_ABORTED; // Return FORMERR?
                        }
 
-                        // avoid R2 offset is outside of the packet error
-                        //if (qname + MAX_DOMAIN_SIZE + 1 > c.end)
-                       //      return XDP_ABORTED; // Return FORMERR?
+                        //avoid R2 offset is outside of the packet error
+                        if (qname + MAX_DOMAIN_SIZE + 1 > c.end)
+                               return XDP_ABORTED; // Return FORMERR?

this change passed the verifier and XDP program loaded ok, but when I test sending DNS query, the if (qname + MAX_DOMAIN_SIZE + 1 > c.end) is always true and result in DNS packet  dropped by return XDP_ABORTED. I guess I am not adding a packet bound check properly before the bpf map lookup, any clue?

Starting at the verifier error
; if (!qname) {
80: (15) if r2 == 0x0 goto pc+7       ; R2_w=pkt(off=62,r=63,imm=0)
; if (bpf_map_lookup_elem(&domain_denylist, qname))
81: (18) r1 = 0xffff93604d4c2400      ; R1_w=map_ptr(off=0,ks=254,vs=1,imm=0)
83: (85) call bpf_map_lookup_elem#1
invalid access to packet, off=62 size=254, R2(id=0,off=62,r=63)

I will translate the relevant bits:

R2_w=pkt(off=62,r=63,imm=0) - Register 2 points to the packet at offset 62, and you have bounds checked up to 63, so you can access 1 byte of data safely.
R1_w=map_ptr(off=0,ks=254,vs=1,imm=0) - Register 1 is a pointer to a map with a key size of 254 bytes, and a value size of 1 byte
call bpf_map_lookup_elem - Calling map lookup helper, where R1 is a pointer to the map, and R2 the value of the map.

The bpf_map_lookup_elem expects to be able to read 254 bytes from R2, but you did not bounds check that amount. That is what the code snipped does
if (qname + MAX_DOMAIN_SIZE + 1 > c.end)
    return XDP_ABORTED;

It asserts that there must at least be 254 bytes bytes in the packet after offset 62. So if you encounter a packet that is smaller than 316 bytes, the program gets aborted. This satisfies the verifier, because when the packet is larger, it can read all 254 bytes and compare with the map.
What you will likely want to do is to record the length of the domain name returned by parse_dname and use it to perform the bounds check. Then prepare a zeroed out buffer of MAX_DOMAIN_SIZE bytes and copy the domain name into the buffer, up to the length of the domain name. You should end up with a buffer the size of you map key padded with zeroes. You can use the buffer to do the lookup.

Hi Dylan, I just made all the changes you suggested, now I got different verifier error, new code is updated as above same link, full verifier error log is  here https://github.com/user-attachments/files/16919433/error.txt, I ran into some other compiler issues when use bpf __builtin_memcpy, I recorded here https://github.com/vincentmli/xdp-tools/issues/1#issuecomment-2335893392

ChatGPT helped avoiding the verifier error https://github.com/vincentmli/xdp-tools/issues/1#issuecomment-2336425362, still need to test the program, not enough confidence with the code :)

ran into another issue that it looks both the qname and buffer domain_key matches record in bpf hash map, but the hash lookup fail and DNS query past through https://github.com/vincentmli/xdp-tools/issues/2

I recommend you join the eBPF slack and ask for help in the #ebpf channel, that is more suited for back and forth communication https://ebpf.io/slack
